# Firebase: accessing empty / non-existent keys and their children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql, database-normalization

So I have a "schema" that looks like this:

```
- orders
  - <$uid>
    - orderid
    - orderid
- transactions
  - <$uid>
    - transactionid
```

I've tried a few ways to access, say, `orders/$uid/orderid` but it looks like if the key itself is null, the result of `.once` or `.on` is never created, even initially.

This is problematic because when adding something to cart, I need to see if user already has a cart / I need to check if it's empty.

I've added a falsy value (`0`, specifically) as a default and now accessing `ref.child('cart/' + user.uid).once()` does in fact return `null`.

The trade-off seems to be that I need to "seed" a new DB with default values or else no events are fired.

Am I missing something or is this a common pattern? If not, what is a better way to deal with null keys essentially being non-existent and not triggering events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
ref.child("orders").orderByChild("orderid").equalTo(orderid).once("value",snapshot => {
var datas=snapshot.val();
if(datas){
  console.log("it exists");
 }
 else{
     console.log("doesn't exist");
  }
});
```

This is the only way, the above will check if the snapshot that is retrieved by `once()` or `on()` exists.

Comment: This is interesting. It does seem wildly hacky or is just me?

Comment: no i think, its the same as doing in android if(datasnapshot.exists()){..}